# View.OnClickListner interface dose not fire onClick method?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-button

```
class TransactionActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener, CalcDialog.CalcDialogCallback {
```

and this is the onClick implemented method

```
   override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            tranBinding.fabSaveTransaction.id -> {
                finish()
            }
            tranBinding.contentTran.btnChooseCurrency.id -> {
                bottomSheetDialog.show()
            }
        }
    }
```

please help me solving this.

Comment: have you set this `OnClickListener` to any `View`?

Comment: can you check whether your btn is clickable via log messages please? maybe you didn't assign event listener to your btns

Comment: At first, you can use a log to understand that onClick method called or not, if the method doesn't call check that your view is clickable or not.

Comment: as @snachmsm point, you have to set this clickListener to the views where you want to use it, you just defined the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Oooh I found where was it my problem
**I forgot to add this line of code**

```
tranBinding.contentTran.btnChooseCurrency.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to set OnClickListener event on every single view like this

```
tranBinding.fabSaveTransaction.setOnClickListener { v -> 
    //your code
}
```